# How do I add a checkbox to an added list?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input, innerhtml

Project: Shopping List

I have created a function that will take input from a form. I am able to display what the user entered. Now I want to add a checkbox next to item displayed, so I can eventually give the option to check the item and remove it.

This is my function:

```
function addItem() {
    var item = [];
    item = document.getElementById('items-listed');
    item.innerHTML += "<li>" + document.form.itemEntered.value + "</li>";
    // item.innerHTML += "<li><input type="checkbox" />" + document.form.itemEntered.value + "</li>";
}
```

I attempted to create the checkbox but it was not working, so I commented it out.

Here is the project running in Code Pen

http://cdpn.io/JGCDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
item.innerHTML += "<li><input type='checkbox'>" + document.form.itemEntered.value + "</li>";
```

The issue you experienced is called escaping.

You are generating a string in JS using double-quotes so if you want to use a literal double-quote inside your string then you need to escape it, please study the code below:

```
item.innerHTML += "<li><input type=\"checkbox\">" + document.form.itemEntered.value + "</li>"; //good
item.innerHTML += '<li><input type="checkbox">' + document.form.itemEntered.value + '</li>'; //good
item.innerHTML += '<li><input type=\'checkbox\'>' + document.form.itemEntered.value + '</li>'; // good

item.innerHTML += "<li><input type="checkbox">" + document.form.itemEntered.value + "</li>"; //bad
item.innerHTML += '<li><input type='checkbox'>' + document.form.itemEntered.value + '</li>'; //bad
```

The devil is always in the details.

Comment: I guess i had to get rid of the > and use single quotes instead of double... Thanks.

Comment: `<input type="checkbox">` and `<input type="checkbox" />` are both valid depending on which HTML/xHTML version you want to validate against. Most modern browsers won't care. The issue you encountered deals with escaping strings and ALL programming languages require proper escaping. Just avoid `<input type="checkbox'>` and you will be a happy camper